Dell Latitude 7640 Intel webcam not working on Ubuntu 24.04
Adapting for 24.04 the solution that was posted here for 22.04 does not solve the problem.
It appears that Intel IPU6 developers have a solution available: https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers/blob/master/README.md
Could someone more knowledgeable please decrypt their instructions and give us a step-by-step guide to build the driver locally?
Thanks.

24.04 is still in Beta. You should report any issue as a bug see https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

@graham 24.04 is not in Beta any more, but the problem persists. (In fact, no updates have been made available by Canonical since my original post).
Thank you for the link, but as far as I can see this is not the appropriate channel to report on faulty drivers.
The Arch Linux community have apparently developed Intel IPU6 drivers for the 6.8.x Linux kernel.
Hopefully we'll also get them from Canonical soon.

I've followed the instructions of the IPU6 developers up to the point where one is to apply the relevant patch file in /ipu6-drivers/patch/v6.8 to change the related Kconfig and Makefile. This is a bash ignorance issue rather than a bug, but can someone advise how to apply this patch in the root tree?

"can someone advise how to apply this patch in the root tree?" I would suggest that you ask a separate question on that issue.
